# Django form modifying HTML tags

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a blog with Django, but I have a problem with the form used to create an article.
When I enter an HTML tag in this form, the output is modified. This is an example :

It looks like this
<a href="http://www.foo/bar.com">This is a link</a>

But when I look at the code it is like this

```
&lt;a href="http://www.foo/bar.com"&gt;This is a link&lt;/a&gt;
```

So do you know how could I make my form return real HTML tags ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to allow HTML tags.

```
{{ content|safe }}
```